# Managing translations for both text and voice over: Logic dead-ends

Tags: design-patterns, design-principles, logic

The tool I am working on can translate some text in different languages. You can also generate a voice-over of individual paragraphs in different languages.

So translations and voice-overs have two different entry points.

Say you add an extra paragraph (for which a translation has not been generated yet), you can still generate a voice-over but the system won't find the translation to read from so it will give you an error.

How should the user be warned? Upon generating the voice-over for the new paragraph should I tell him/her, "Please update the translations before proceeding?"

I have run into a series of dead-ends for which I don't just want to place a warning as a fix. I wonder how to define the logic above that guides the user through a process, yet allowing him/her freedom of exploration.

Comment: This is far too broad to give a specific, correct answer to. We can help with specific UX problems, but if you want advice on how to learn about UX as a whole then that's too big a remit for a UX Q&A site to advise on.

Comment: Fair. thanks for this, helped me. I just re-phrased the question.

Comment: @JonW, do you mind opening the question? I have re-phrased it. Let me know. thanks

Comment: OK, reopened. Thanks for updating it.

Comment: Feels like more information might be required to answer the question, because it is a catch-22 situation of whether the process defines the interface or if you want to use the interface to define the process.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are some additional scenarios to consider, at least if my understanding of the question is correct.

You have referred to both translation and voice over features, which implies that there would be source and target texts (to be translated) as well as voice over for the original and translated text (that you can add voice over to).

So when you talk about adding an extra paragraph, can't the voice-over be generated for both the source and target language, or does it trigger an error only for certain combinations (e.g. only source but not target language)? The error handling should be consistent to cater for a potential number of different scenarios:

- Source text exists, user wants to generate voice over for translated text, which triggers error
- Changes made to source text, translation not updated and therefore voice over generated is not correct because translation needs to be updated
- Any other combination of source text, target text, original voice over and translated voice over that can be triggered

I think if you can define the workflow and create a consistent process using the interface, it will avoid some of these logic dead-ends that you are referring to.

Comment: Thanks. I will get back to you on this as I need to reflect on the answer.

I think the translations part is solved and solid. You edit the text in the original language, from a panel you can generate translations and within that panel you can also amend these translations. Then if you make any changes to the original, a notification on the translations tab warns you that there is a mis-match, so user can easily click UPDATE, and all translations are regenerated and now match the original. Status is communicated, user knows how the system is. Now, according to industry standard..

Comment: ..only after translations the voice-overs are recorded. So the process is Original-translations-voice overs in various languages. Solid but rigid, limits exploration.
In my case, for AI generated voice over, voice over has to come after text is written and translated, no way around that. So if user shortens the text, he sees (from the notification) that translations now need an updated, doesn't updated them, now if he wants the V.O. in the original yes he can have it, but for translations will prompt an error..
Dunno how to get how of this loop